# get the substring using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have set of  string in below  formats

```
Local Tax 02/07 02/14 -0.42
```

I want to split the above as three separate stings like

```
Local Tax
02/07 02/14
-0.42
```

I wrote the following code snippet

```
package com.demo;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class DemoClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s ="Sales Tax 08/07 09/06 0.42";
        //String s1 = "Sales Tax 02/07 02/14 -1.02";
         Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z ]*) ([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}) ([-[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]])");
         Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
         if (matcher.find()) {
             System.out.println("String Name::"+s);
             System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
             System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
             System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
        }    
    }
}
```

and I am getting output as

```
String Name::Sales Tax 08/07 09/06 0.42
Sales Tax
08/07 09/06
0
```

the **matcher.group(3)** should return 0.42 but it is displaying as 0. could some help me on this please.

Answer (score 1):

`.` is a special character in Regular Expressions, which matches (almost) any character (see **[more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)**). Escaping `.` would make your regex work just fine (I also simplified the last part by making the `-` optional (see **[more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)**)):

```
^([a-zA-Z ]*) ([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}) (-?[0-9]*\\.[0-9][0-9])
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/OZHE59)**.

Comment: Always glad to help :) See my updated answers for a couple of links you might find useful.

Comment: @user2394281: Please, consider marking this answer as "accepted", since it seems to have helped you solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This will give the 0.42 response.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z ]*) ([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}) ([0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]*.[0-9][0-9])");
```

Comment: @Talipkorkmaz.. but this pattern will not match for "Sales Tax 02/07 02/14 -1.02"

Comment: When i saw the question, there was no information about minus sign.It seems you edited your post.Yes yu are right this will not work for string with minus.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, provided your 3rd value always starts with a "-" sign.

```
        String test = "Local Tax 02/07 02/14 -0.42";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=\\p{Alpha})\\s(?=\\d))|((?<=\\d)\\s(?=-\\d))");
        String[] result = pattern.split(test);
        for (String partial: result) {
            System.out.println(partial);
        }
```

**Edit** If your third value is not necessarily negative, try this instead (same output):

```
        String test = "Local Tax 02/07 02/14 -0.42";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?<=\\p{Alpha})\\s(?=\\d))|((?<=\\d)\\s(?=\\p{Punct}?[\\d\\.]+?$))");
        String[] result = pattern.split(test);
        for (String partial: result) {
            System.out.println(partial);
        }
```

Output:

```
Local Tax
02/07 02/14
-0.42
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^([a-zA-Z ]*) (\\d{2}/\\d{2} \\d{2}/\\d{2}) (-?\\d+(?:\.\\d{2})?)
```